# Trying to understand syntax with index slicing in python matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numerical-analysis, numpy-slicing

I have been looking over and interpreting some sample code and am having some trouble understanding what is going on with a bit of slicing syntax. For some context I am working on a computational program that uses method of finite differences approximating temperatures over a square region.

Here is some of the code:

```
maxIter = 500
lenX = lenY = 20 
delta = 1
Ttop = 100
Tbottom = 0
Tleft = 0
Tright = 0
Tguess = 30

T = np.empty((lenX, lenY))
T.fill(Tguess)

T[(lenY-1):, :] = Ttop
T[:1, :] = Tbottom
T[:, (lenX-1):] = Tright
T[:, :1] = Tleft
```

the last bit is what I am having trouble understanding. I am unsure exactly what the placement of the colons and commas are doing in the T[] boundary conditions. The next part of the code proceeds with for loops with T[i,j]. 
Like looking at the first one it seems to say in first index of T slice from 9 (lenY-1) to the end of the list and in the second index dont slice anything, then it sets that to 100. I understand this is making the temp along the top boundary 100, I am just not sure how that is happening from the syntax present.

Answer (score 2):

The colon expressions are transferred as [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) objects to the numpy array. A comma creates a tuple. For demonstration:

```
class A:
    def __setitem__(self, target, data):
        print(repr(target))
        print(repr(data))

a = A()
a[17:, :] = 6
```

prints:

```
(slice(17, None, None), slice(None, None, None))
6
```

So you could also write:

```
a[(slice(17, None, None), slice(None, None, None))] = 6
```

in the last line to have the same result.

It is then the duty of the class (e.g. numpy array) to interpret that in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose `x` is a NumPy array with N elements, indexed 0..N-1. You can say `x[:k]` to indicate all the elements from 0..k-1, `x[k:]` to indicate k..N-1, and `x[k1:k2]` to indicate k1..k2-1. And finally, `x[:]` indicates all the elements.

So in your code, the four lines are setting:

- last row, all columns to `Ttop`
- first row, all columns to `Tbottom`
- all rows, last column to `Tright`
- all rows, first column to `Tleft`

The documentation for slicing may be a good reference going forward: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

You can quickly prove this to yourself by printing `T` after each operation in the Python command line interface. Start python, `import numpy as np`, change `lenX` and `lenY` to something small to make it easier to read, and change the initialization values to all be unique so we can track the changes:

```
>>> lenX = lenY = 5
>>> Ttop = 100
>>> Tbottom = 200
>>> Tleft = 300
>>> Tright = 400
>>> Tguess = 30
>>> T = np.empty((lenX, lenY))
>>> T.fill(Tguess)
```

Then away we go:

```
>>> T[(lenY-1):, :] = Ttop
>>> T
array([[ 30.,  30.,  30.,  30.,  30.],
       [ 30.,  30.,  30.,  30.,  30.],
       [ 30.,  30.,  30.,  30.,  30.],
       [ 30.,  30.,  30.,  30.,  30.],
       [100., 100., 100., 100., 100.]])
>>> T[:1, :] = Tbottom
>>> T
array([[200., 200., 200., 200., 200.],
       [ 30.,  30.,  30.,  30.,  30.],
       [ 30.,  30.,  30.,  30.,  30.],
       [ 30.,  30.,  30.,  30.,  30.],
       [100., 100., 100., 100., 100.]])
>>> T[:, (lenX-1):] = Tright
>>> T
array([[200., 200., 200., 200., 400.],
       [ 30.,  30.,  30.,  30., 400.],
       [ 30.,  30.,  30.,  30., 400.],
       [ 30.,  30.,  30.,  30., 400.],
       [100., 100., 100., 100., 400.]])
>>> T[:, :1] = Tleft
>>> T
array([[300., 200., 200., 200., 400.],
       [300.,  30.,  30.,  30., 400.],
       [300.,  30.,  30.,  30., 400.],
       [300.,  30.,  30.,  30., 400.],
       [300., 100., 100., 100., 400.]])
```